# GWT - Many Class not supported, but still works

Tags: gwt

Im making my own application by using GWT framework. I say that many Class are not supported (like Calendar, Connection, Statement, DriverManager, ResultSet, etc etc) but i can use it (they works).

Is it normal? :) And should they be replaced?

EXAMPLE :

when application start, it loads some FlowPanel with some buttons. When i click on the menu_login_button i do the asynch call

```
package org.sinfonet.client;

public class PageMenuLogin extends FlowPanel {
    private PageCenter center;
    public PageMenuLogin(PageCenter center) {
        this.center=center;
        designLogin();
    }

    public void designLogin() {
        final InlineLabel menu_login_label1=new InlineLabel("Username");
        menu_login_label1.setStyleName("menu_span");
        this.add(menu_login_label1);
        final TextBox menu_login_input1 = new TextBox();
        menu_login_input1.setText("admin");
        this.add(menu_login_input1);
        final InlineLabel menu_login_label2=new InlineLabel("Password");
        menu_login_label2.setStyleName("menu_span");
        this.add(menu_login_label2);
        final TextBox menu_login_input2 = new TextBox();
        menu_login_input2.setText("pass");
        this.add(menu_login_input2);
        Button menu_login_button=new Button("Login");
        this.add(menu_login_button);

        PageMenuLogin.this.center.getContent().clear();
        PageMenuLogin.this.center.getContent().add(new TitleContent("Homepage"));
        PageMenuLogin.this.center.getContent().add(new Main());

        final AsyncCallback<java.lang.Boolean> callCheckLogin = new AsyncCallback<java.lang.Boolean>() {
            public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                if(result) {
                    designLogout(menu_login_input1.getText());
                } else {
                    menu_err.setText("Username e password non validi");
                }
            }

            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                menu_login_label1.setText("Comunicazione Fallita");
            }
        };

        menu_login_button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                getService().checkLogin(menu_login_input1.getText(), menu_login_input2.getText(), callCheckLogin);
            }
        });
    }

    public void designLogout(String login_user) {
        PageMenuLogin.this.center.getContent().add(new Profile(login_user));
    }

    public static GWTServiceAsync getService() {
        return GWT.create(GWTService.class);
    }
}
```

right now, under you can see the asynch call, where (as you said) i can put every kind of server calls (database, resultset, statement, ecc)

```
package org.sinfonet.server;

public class GWTServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GWTService {
    public boolean checkLogin(String nickname, String password) {
        Database mydb=Configuration.getDatabase();
        mydb.connetti();

        // faccio md5 ed escape
        String log_check_user=nickname;
        String log_check_pass=password;

        // controllo che l'utente esista
        ArrayList<String[]> db_result=null;
        db_result=mydb.selectQuery("SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE nickname='"+log_check_user+"' AND password='"+log_check_pass+"'");
        if(db_result.size()!=0) {
            return true;
        }

        // sconnessione al database
        mydb.disconnetti();

        return false;
    }
}
```

if the function return true, i can load the Profile class (which is client side).

```
package org.sinfonet.client.profile;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.InlineLabel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import org.sinfonet.server.mgmt.Configuration;
import org.sinfonet.server.mgmt.Database;

public class Profile extends FlowPanel {
    private String[] record;
    private String value;
    private TextBox field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5;
    private TextArea field_A;

    private FlowPanel profilo_1=new FlowPanel();
    private FlowPanel profilo_2=new FlowPanel();
    private FlowPanel profilo_3=new FlowPanel();
    private FlowPanel pm_inbox=new FlowPanel();
    private FlowPanel pm_outbox=new FlowPanel();
    private FlowPanel pm_button=new FlowPanel();

    public Profile(String value) {
        // memorizzo nome utente
        this.value=value;

        // imposto div principale
        this.setStyleName("content_span");
        profilo_1.setStyleName("profilo_1");
        profilo_2.setStyleName("profilo_2");
        profilo_3.setStyleName("profilo_3");
        pm_inbox.setStyleName("pm_cont1");
        pm_outbox.setStyleName("pm_cont2");
        pm_button.setStyleName("pm_but");
        this.add(profilo_1);
        this.add(profilo_2);
        this.add(profilo_3);
        designMainProfile();
    }

    public final void designMainProfile() {
        Database mydb=Configuration.getDatabase();

        mydb.connetti();
        mydb.disconnetti();
    }
}
```

If i well understand, i can't call Database functions when i load Profile (because its a client class).

So, how can i fix it? I do an asynch call when im loading Profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of pointers first.

1. Never include anything in *.server
   in a class in *.client.
2. The opposite of the above is also
   true: never include anything in
   *.client in a class in *.server.
3. The server end points of gwt rpc's
   are in *.server, and end in Impl.
   They can do server things.
4. The client end points of gwt rpc's
   are in *.client, and one of them
   ends in Async. The other isn't
   appended with anything. These two
   files are interfaces, and therefore
   have no logic.

replace callCheckLogin in PageMenuLogin with the following:

```
public class PageMenuLogin extends FlowPanel {
...
  public void designLogin() {
        final InlineLabel menu_login_label1 = new InlineLabel("Username");
        menu_login_label1.setStyleName("menu_span");
        this.add(menu_login_label1);
        final TextBox menu_login_input1 = new TextBox();
        menu_login_input1.setText("admin");
        this.add(menu_login_input1);
        final InlineLabel menu_login_label2 = new InlineLabel("Password");
        menu_login_label2.setStyleName("menu_span");
        this.add(menu_login_label2);
        final TextBox menu_login_input2 = new TextBox();
        menu_login_input2.setText("pass");
        this.add(menu_login_input2);
        Button menu_login_button = new Button("Login");
        this.add(menu_login_button);

        this.center.getContent().clear();
        this.center.getContent().add(new TitleContent("Homepage"));
        this.center.getContent().add(new Main());

        menu_login_button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                getService().checkLogin(menu_login_input1.getText(),
                        menu_login_input2.getText(),
                        new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                menu_login_label1
                                        .setText("Comunicazione Fallita");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                                if (result) {
                                    designLogout(menu_login_input1.getText());
                                } else {
                                    menu_err.setText("Username e password non validi");
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
```

replace designMainProfile in Profile with the following:

```
    public final void designMainProfile() {

        PageMenuLogin.getService().foo(new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

In GWTServiceImpl, add the following:

```
@Override
    public void foo() {
        Database mydb = Configuration.getDatabase();

        mydb.connetti();
        mydb.disconnetti();

    }
```

In GWTService, add the following:

```
void foo();
```

In GWTServiceAsync, add the following:

```
void foo(AsyncCallback<Void> asyncCallback);
```

If you don't have either of the last two classes, let me know, and we'll back up a couple steps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Is not so much clear what i'm doing by using your code! In fact, i'm doing 2 asynch call (but im not sure). So, if i have understand : The first asynch call start when i click on the menu_login_button, which will load the Profile() class (coded in javascript, client side). The second is called when the Profile() class (the one, in fact, coded in JS) is loaded on the browser. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, two rpc invocations. One to do the login logic, and one to do the profile logic. The second, foo, which I only stubbed out to move your server code to the server, doesn't do anything useful. You'd have to pass it some parameters and/or return a value.

Comment: Yes. Now is clear how GWT works (or at least, the basics functions)! Really man, thanks, you make my day :)

Comment: Last thing : you said "he opposite of the above is also true: never include anything in *.client in a class in *.server." but if you look to the usual GWTServiceImpl (which is in a .server package) you can see import org.sinfonet.client.GWTService; (but maybe this make sense because GWTService its only an interface?!?!) :)

Comment: @markzzz good catch. there are exceptions, rpc interfaces being one of them.

Answer (score 3):

One thing is that you can add them to your code and your IDE doesn't show any problem, another thing is that your application can compile and be executed as a GWT application.

Take a look to [RefJREEmulation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) documentation.

Comment: Perfect. But i need these classes...i need to use the GWT ones?

Comment: GWT doesn't support Calendar or ResultSet or a lot of other Java classes. If you need them you can either create some calls to the server side to get the needed info or create your own wrappers in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah...im using this function server side :) When i do an asynch call for example, i use Statement or ResultSet to get values from database. But they are not supported o_O

Comment: If I'm understanding you properly, your problem is that you're returning unsupported Classes in your Async Calls. You can use whatever Java classes you want in your server side, but when you return classes to the client side (GWT) those MUST be JREEmulation supported.
You should convert your ResultSet to ArrayList, your Calendar to Date and so on.
Sadlyl there's no work around. GWT converts your code to JavaScript so it has some limitations.

Comment: @markzzz: Your users' browsers can't connect to your database via `"jdbc:..."` - The browser talks to your application server, and it can only use a few protocols (`"http:..."`, `"https:..."`, maybe `"ftp:..."`) to do that. This is the reason, why GWT doesn't make `java.sql.Connection` etc. available on the client side. Even a `ResultSet` usually needs an open jdbc Connection.

Comment: Yes of course. And no, i don't return any type of object at the client (only string)... maybe i can post a piece of code?

Comment: I've added a piece of code, so you can see the error when i call Database mydb=Configuration.getDatabase();

Comment: @markzz: As Chris said and as I said before. You're mixing classes. You CAN NOT use not supported JREEmulation classes in your GWT code.
In the example you're calling a Database class, which uses java.sql imports DIRECTLY from GWT. Please take a look to the RPC methods, since those calls should be in the SERVER side.

Comment: uhm..i making a bit of confusion. In some minuts a post a small example! thanks to your time, but i need to clear this situation (probably i make a wrong structure of the website) :)

Comment: You can understand what i'm looking for right now, i hope the example is clear :)

Comment: in fact, what i don't understand is WHY :) When i call Profile() (with .add(new Profile()) im on server side. So i must be able to dialogate with database... is not JS client side that create Profile(), is the server (by calling an asynch function). Right?

Comment: @markszzz: No, the `onSuccess()` method is executed on the client side, after the server request has completed succesfully. `onSuccess()` executes `designLogout()`, which executes `new Profile()`. So all of that happens on the client side.

Comment: Uhn. But if i put only logic UI widgets in Profile() class, they will displayed on the browser. So, how can the GWT know how to get them? I dubt GWT will include these methods/widgets in the javascript client side when i compile it o_O

Comment: This answer and related discussion is missing the question, which is "how can i fix it?", ie, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right. With this topic i understand how GWT works more or less, i did totally wrong about this framework :) Can i ask to you the last thing? (You can say easly yes or no :)) : my functions (like designLogout or designLogin) is coded on JS when i compile it, right? So when i do the asynch call and with onSuccess i load designLogin, it just return somethings to the client that load that function, right? But it was already loaded client-side as JS, right? :) Thanks for your effort...

Comment: @markszzz: I have the impression you jumped into GWT without fully understanding its limitations. Take a look to the GWT page, specially to http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html
If you still have questions, contact me in private and I'll try to help

Comment: I read that document many time :) But it doesnt explain what i ask before, or maybe the real limitation is my english hehe! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yeah in fact i done some test with Fiddler, and i see that i proper understand what happens when i call those functions. In fact, i won't take this way. I want to create client-code "at the moment", not create it as JS and load it when an asynch call occuurs. So, is it possible made UI object server side and send it to the client? I think it will be better... P.S. I should send to you PM, but i don't know how to contact you in private :)

Comment: In few words : is it possible to create a GWT UI FlowPanel on server-side and send it to the client? :)

Comment: So, in less words, if i have to load dinamic content (div, table, span, and so on) i can't. I need to made is at JS (client-side) and "activate/show" them using asynch call?

Comment: I concur with @Carlos; you seem to be missing a few concepts of GWT and App Engine interaction. I suggest you start with the example project eclipse generates and play around with it to get a good handle on the gwtrpc structure/interactions.

Comment: Dynamic content must be fetched with rpc calls, of which AsyncCallback classes handle the results of, and in general the gui must be generated on the client side.

Comment: I read the Netbans and the Ecplise introduction to GWT, tried the examples, examined the code and filtered by Fiddler to see what is the traffic from client-server. I just need an example that show how to send div/span (flowpanel/inlaylabel on gwt) from server to client. But i think i can't do it, right?